# Use of uninitialized in Text::CSV::Hashify

Tags: perl, csv

I'm a beginner. I am trying to assign values from a CSV file to a hash. I get tired all day. I'm closing my hands already. My csv:

```
currency,asset,exchange,strategy,profit,profitday,yearlyprofit,marketchange,profitmarket,tradeamount,tradesday,winingtrades,lossetrades,percentagewins,bestwin,medianwins,worstloss,medianloss,candlesize,warmupperiod,daysofdataset,backteststart,datasetfrom,datasetto,pricevolality,note
USD,BTC,bitfinex,BBRSI,0.00,-1,0,-2.55,2.55,0,-1,0,0,-1,,na,,na,5,144,0,"2018-03-25 01:15:39","2018-03-24 00:00:00","2018-03-24 12:00:00",11.20,"shorter period"
USD,XMR,bitfinex,BBRSI,0.00,-1,0,-2.18,2.18,0,-1,0,0,-1,,na,,na,5,144,0,"2018-03-25 01:15:39","2018-03-24 00:00:00","2018-03-24 12:00:00",17.41,"shorter period"
```

At line end is \r\n.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $csvfile = 'gekko/backtestbitfinex/testowy.csv';

my $obj;
use Text::CSV::Hashify;


# Object-oriented interface
use Text::CSV::Hashify;
$obj = Text::CSV::Hashify->new( {
file => $csvfile,
format => 'hoh', # hash of hashes, which is default
key => 'asa',
#eol => '\r\n',
sep_char => ',',
quote_char => '',
escape_char => '',
binary => 1,
decode_utf8 => 0,
auto_diag => 1,
diag_verbose => 1,
blank_is_undef => 0,
empty_is_undef => 0,
allow_whitespace => 1,
allow_loose_quotes => 1,
allow_loose_escapes => 1,
allow_unquoted_escape => 1,
always_quote => 1,
quote_empty => 1,
quote_space => 1,
escape_null => 1,
quote_binary => 1,
keep_meta_info => 1,
verbatim => 0,


} ); 
print Dumper \$obj;
```

Output error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $kk in hash element at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Text/CSV/Hashify.pm line 353, <GEN0> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $kk in hash element at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Text/CSV/Hashify.pm line 357, <GEN0> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $kk in hash element at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Text/CSV/Hashify.pm line 359, <GEN0> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $kk in hash element at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Text/CSV/Hashify.pm line 353, <GEN0> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $kk in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Text/CSV/Hashify.pm line 354, <GEN0> line 3.
Key '' already seen at csv.pl line 13.
```

By default When I set: `eol => '\r\n',` get error: `'_ERROR_DIAG' => 'EOF - End of data in parsing input stream',`

What's wrong with my CSV?

Comment: One item to change in your code would be `key => 'asset',`

Comment: I have released a new version of Text::CSV::Hashify to CPAN to address some of the concerns raised in this thread.  See http://search.cpan.org/~jkeenan/Text-CSV-Hashify-0.11/.  See also https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=125384 and https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=125385.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a cursory look at the module:
You specified 'asa' as a key, but your data missing that field.
This causes the: `Key '' already seen at csv.pl line 13.`

The warnings show up because you run the script with `-w` option (and also because the module author didn't take care of uninitialized variables).

In general you use `no warnings 'uninitialized';` to silence expected warnings that come from *your* code (scoping it to the smallest block necessary).

In this case the warnings have come from the module code that you don't control (well, you can patch it, but this of course should be avoided).
To alleviate the problem you can:

- do not override module's warnings levels with `-w`, use `use warnings`, which applies only to your code.
- trap warnings coming from the module with `$SIG{__WARN__} = \&handler_sub`, (more details: `perldoc perlvar` -> `%SIG`).  This is not guaranteed to work with every module though.

Comment: Do not use "no warnings". Use warnings to discover problems in your code, so always put "use strict; use warnings;" (on 2 lines) in all your progams.

Comment: `no warnings 'uninitialized';` won't make a difference. If the warning is indeed spurious, remove `-w` and add `use warnings qw( all );`.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Don't be so sure about "no warnings". Just run `grep -r --include='*.pm' 'no warnings'  . | wc -l ` in your perl/lib directory. For me it returns about 150 occurrences.

Comment: And? The fact that others are doing a mistake justify to do the same? Even more that should justify giving this very bad advice to a beginner, the exact target that would get useful help from such feature?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek perl/lib is the standard perl distribution. They put "no warnings" there for the very practical purposes, it is *not* a mistake.   As to beginners, I 've rewritten my answer to be more clear about the scope of "no warnings".   And yes, it actually does not apply for this case.

Comment: And so (again) ? Writers of module inside the perl standard distribution have probably just a tad better experience than the poster or any Perl beginner. So giving a beginner an advice to remove "use warnings" is just plain wrong, this is not debatable. When the beginner will have enough experience to understand what "use warnings" does and why sometimes we can do without then and only then he could remove it. But starting to develop in Perl without "use strict; use warnings;" is just very very bad advice.

Comment: The warnings show up because the library is not used as it should. Use the library correctly and you will not  get warnings.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I never adviced anyone to remove `use warnings`.  And adding the disclaimer `use strict; use warnings;` into every answer is just plain silly.

Comment: Yes, you edited your answer multiple times. The first one was: put no warnings 'uninitialized';  This is a bad advice and I will stop there. Put "use strict; use warnings;" in any code when you begin is the right way to learn Perl and would probably cut the number of questions here by half just with that.

Comment: I file [this issue](https://github.com/jkeenan/text-csv-hashify/issues/4) on Hashify git repo.